# Terraform to read variables from environment

Tags: continuous-integration, terraform, continuous-deployment

I have written a terraform configuration with variable definition like:

```
variable "GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION" {
  type = string
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` I am asked to fill in this variable even though this variable is set within my environment.

Is there a way to tell terraform to work with current env vars? Or do I have to export them and pass them somehow manually one-by-one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define the environment variable `TF_VAR_GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION` to set that variable.

If you are using bash, it might look like this:

```
export TF_VAR_GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION="$GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION"
terraform apply ...
```

[From Environment Variables under Configuration Language: Input Variables.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#environment-variables)

> As a fallback for the other ways of defining variables, Terraform searches the environment of its own process for environment variables named `TF_VAR_` followed by the name of a declared variable.
>
> This can be useful when running Terraform in automation, or when running a sequence of Terraform commands in succession with the same variables. For example, at a `bash` prompt on a Unix system:
>
> $ export TF_VAR_image_id=ami-abc123
>      $ terraform plan
>      ...

Comment: Yeah I read that. I was just wondering if I can somehow replicate directly from the current env vars. This basically means I need to iterate all of them and prepend them with this prefix.

Comment: I would use aws_region and aws_caller_identity data sources myself and switch these variables to locals since they will match the provider anyway, but you are using GCP and I can't find equivalent data sources to cover all of that. A loop through the variables may be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

[You can create a file that ends with `.tfvars` or `.tfvars.json`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) and then when you run a `plan` you specify that file:

```
terraform apply -var-file="example.tfvars"
```

If you name the file `terraform.tfvars` or `terraform.tfvars.json` or have a file with names ending in `.auto.tfvars` or `.auto.tfvars.json`
then Terraform **automatically** loads the variable definition file and you don't have to manually specify it when you run a `plan`.

An example of what the `terraform.tfvars` file will look like:

```
first_env_var = "environment_variable_one"
second_env_var = "environment_variable_two"
```

An example of what the `terraform.tfvars.json` file will look like:

```
{
  "image_id": "ami-abc123",
  "availability_zone_names": ["us-west-1a", "us-west-1c"]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This actually does answer the question and is a solid method for handling variables you want to vary by TF workspace or environment you're building towards.  There are many ways to handle the question you asked and I think this is the most common and straight forward way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by creating a variables.tf file, within the project directory. with the required variable block you can specify a default:

```
variable "GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION" {
  type = string
  default = "us-west1"
}
```

this will then be used as the default value during each run, and you will not be prompted.

Comment: If you have a value that you never modify, this is perfectly fine.  I would add, if it never changes, then don't make it a variable especially if it is used in one place.